# How to remove quotes around string using glue_sql() and sub() inside a loop?

Tags: r

My code sample :

```
fields <- data.frame(names=c("A", "B"))

variables <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(fields)) {
 
  variables[[i]] <- fields$names[i]
  
  query <- glue_sql("UPDATE schema1.table1 a SET {variables } = (
                      SELECT {variables} FROM schema2.table2 b WHERE b.id_obs = a.id_obs)", .con = pool)
```

Output:

```
<SQL> UPDATE schema1.table1 a SET 'A' = (
SELECT 'A' FROM public.test1 b WHERE b.id_obs = a.id_obs)
<SQL> UPDATE schema1.table1 a SET 'B' = (
SELECT 'B' FROM public.test1 b WHERE b.id_obs = a.id_obs)
```

I'm wondering how can I remove the quotes around my variable_names (A and B) in the output ?

I tried to add `query <- sub("('.*?')",  variables, query)` but I don't really understand the behaviour of sub() within my loop...

Could someone help me out please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` instead:

```
query <- gsub("'", '',glue_sql("UPDATE schema1.table1 a SET {variables } = (
                  SELECT {variables} FROM schema2.table2 b WHERE b.id_obs = a.id_obs)", .con = pool) )
```

Comment: I just checked the difference between sub and gsub: "The sub() function will replace the first occurrence leaving the other as it is. On the other hand, the gsub() function will replace all the strings or values with the input strings." ! Thanks @Tur it was what I was looking for :)